# Marginal Distribution.

Tags: probability-distributions

Consider a couple of real random variables $(X,Y)$ and $\mu_{X,Y}$ the induced probability distribution.
Denote by $\mu_X$ and $\mu_Y$ the distributions of $X$ and $Y$.

Is it true that 
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}f(x)\ d\mu_{X,Y}(x,y)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)d\mu_{X}\quad ?$$
This is true each time you can use Fubini theorem. For example, if the random variables are discrete or indepedent or if $(X,Y)$ admits a density with respect to the Lebesgue measure.

I don't know if it is true in the general case, I don't find any counterexample.

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: isn't by definition $P(x)=\int P(x,y)dy$, so $\int f(x)P(x,y)dxdy=\int f(x)P(x)dx$

Comment: What is your assumption about $f$?